# Android Azure Mobile Services Offline Sync Soft Delete

Tags: android, .net, azure, soft-delete

I've implemented an Android App which supports Azure Mobile Services and Offline Sync. I have been testing it with two different devices. I do a delete operation (soft delete) on the first device and that works ok. I then let it sync, check the server side record that the Deleted column has 'true' marked which it does. But I cannot seem to get the second tablet to sync to reflect the new changes i.e. do not display the deleted record.

To enable soft delete I have added enableSoftDelete: true into the table controllers on the app service on Azure. I've not touched my app in terms of the delete process but below is a typical delete:

```
    Save save = getSave(SaveID);
try {
            mtblSave.delete(save);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

I'm using .NET backend with Azure SQL Server.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot seem to get the second tablet to sync to reflect the new changes i.e. do not display the deleted record.

As [Using soft delete in Mobile Services](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-using-soft-delete.md) mentioned as follows:

> **When using the [Offline data Sync for Mobile Services](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data.md) feature, the client SDK automatically queries for deleted records and removes them from the local database**. Without soft delete enabled, you need to write additional code on the backend so that the client SDK knows which records to remove from the local store. Otherwise, the client local store and backend will be inconsistent with regard to these deleted records and the client method `PurgeAsync()` must be called to clear the local store.

I assumed that you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when handling pull operation. Also, you could add [includeDeleted](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/query/ExecutableQuery.html#includeDeleted--) method when you construct the query for pulling data as follows for a better understanding of this feature.

```
var pullQuery = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class).where().field("complete").eq(false).includeDeleted();
mToDoTable.pull(mPullQuery).get();
```

Additionally, for more details about using offline data sync in Mobile Services, you could refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-android-get-started-offline-data.md).

**UPDATE:**

The query parameter is an optional query to filter results.

As [How offline synchronization works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) mentioned about **Incremental Sync**:

> If you use a non-null queryId, the Azure Mobile SDK performs an incremental sync. Each time a pull operation returns a set of results, the latest updatedAt timestamp from that result set is stored in the SDK local system tables. Subsequent pull operations retrieve only records after that timestamp.
>
> **The query name can be any string you choose, but it must be unique for each logical query in your app. Otherwise, different pull operations could overwrite the same incremental sync timestamp and your queries can return incorrect results**.

You could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723489/syncing-problems-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-easy-tables/44752768#44752768) and troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I've actually think I've found the problem. I changed my sync method from `mtblSave.pull(null, "tblsave").get();` to `mtblSave.pull(null).get();` and it dragged down all the changed records. The code that wasn't working was for Incremental Sync which I thought would work. Is there a problem with my Incremental Sync code? Do I need to actually put a query?

Comment: I updated my answer, you could refer to the explanation.

Comment: Hi thanks for that but I do not fully understand the part you put in bold. Using `mtblSave.pull(null, "tblsave").get();` isn't that a unique queryid of 'tblSave' so when it is called again it will check updatedAt? What is the difference between the method i used and the one mentioned in your other answer `await coffeeTable.PullAsync("allCoffees", coffeeTable.CreateQuery());`?

Comment: The code from another issue is written by c#. The first parameter is queryid, the second is the query. I assumed the table structure for storing latest updateat timestamp is the same. Your code looks well, but as you said that the incremental sync could not work as excepted, I just add some notes and approaches for you to locate this issue.

Comment: I've started using the azure mobile services debugging and the outgoing query is as follows `https://[APPNAME].azurewebsites.net/tables/tblsave?$filter=updatedAt%20ge%20(datetimeoffset%272017-08-16T16:17:11.516Z%27)&$top=50&$orderby=updatedAt%20asc`. In theory this should retrieve records later than 16th Aug 17 time 16:17 right? There are definately records which are newer than that but I'm getting back nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Think i've got it. Your include delete query wasn't doing anything for some reason, so I changed it a little and I believe the soft delete and incremental sync is working now. So the sync query was `mtblSave.pull(null, "tblsave").get();` and this has changed to `Query pullQuery = QueryOperations.field("Id").ne(val("")).includeDeleted();
                    mtblSave.pull(pullQuery, "tblsave").get();` Don't think getting all records by asking for not null Id values is the correct way. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: So your answer of adding includeDeleted was correct so I will accept this as the answer.