# Should we push and pull all tables all the time for offline snyc?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am not able to understand the concept of azure mobile offline sync using xamarin.forms. I followed [this](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/) article and samples.

1)  according to this, I must push all changes and pull all tables. 
It looks like that push all tables according to the code [here](https://github.com/adrianhall/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/blob/master/Chapter3/TaskList/TaskList/Services/AzureCloudService.cs)

```
public async Task SyncOfflineCacheAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SyncOfflineCacheAsync: Initializing...");
            await InitializeAsync();

            // Push the Operations Queue to the mobile backend
            Debug.WriteLine("SyncOfflineCacheAsync: Pushing Changes");
            await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            // Pull each sync table
            Debug.WriteLine("SyncOfflineCacheAsync: Pulling tags table");
            var tagTable = await GetTableAsync<Tag>(); await tagTable.PullAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("SyncOfflineCacheAsync: Pulling tasks table");
            var taskTable = await GetTableAsync<TodoItem>(); await taskTable.PullAsync();
        }
```

Why should I get all tables everytime, isnt it an expensive operation? I debugged it, it always call GetAll function in the backend? what is the advantage of this usage?

2)  If I only change Complete of TodoItem, Should I push entire item or is there a way to push only Complete with Id information? I read in the documentation that it should be possible but I cant find how.

```
 public class TodoItem : TableData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }

        public string TagId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1) according to this, I must push all changes and pull all tables.

As [How offline synchronization works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync#how-sync-works) states about the **Push** operation:

> Push is an operation on the sync context and sends all CUD changes since the last push. **Note that it is not possible to send only an individual table's changes, because otherwise operations could be sent out of order**. Push executes a series of REST calls to your Azure Mobile App backend, which in turn modifies your server database.

For `Pull` operation, you could leverage **Incremental Sync** which would retrieve the records after the latest `updatedAt` timestamp stored in your local SQLite table. Details you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723489/syncing-problems-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-easy-tables/44752768#44752768). Also, you could follow the **Query Management** section in adrian hall's book [The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

> 2) If I only change Complete of TodoItem, Should I push entire item or is there a way to push only Complete with Id information?

AFAIK, you could not achieve this purpose, since the client SDK handles this processing for you and executes a set of REST calls to your mobile app backend.

Comment: Hmm, so if you create 1400 row items and call Sync() then it calls Post, 1400 times. Seems like MS could have gave us a way to override or group updates.